# Logout using react Native DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, logout, react-navigation

I am building a react-native app([App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11BdM.png))which has Logout link on the Drawer Navigator.

Code is as below

```
 const DrawerScreen = DrawerNavigator({
    ..........
    logout: {
        screen: Component   
    },
})

export default DrawerScreen;
```

But the problem is , it's only loading the component screen. i need to call a method where i can perform Asyncstorage clear and navigate to LoginPage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably want to add a button to your drawer. 
If so, your code will look like this.

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
    mainpage:{screen:MyScreen}
},
{
    contentComponent:(props) => (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
                <DrawerItems {...props} />
                <Button title="Logout" onPress={DO_SOMETHING_HERE}/>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    ),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
})
```

You should import `import {DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation';` to get it work.

**UPDATE:**

1. In 4.x version of react-navigation you should import `import **{DrawerNavigatorItems}** from **'react-navigation-drawer'**
2. You should import **SafeAreaView** from 'react-native-safe-area-view'

Comment: Inside the onPress, how can I navigate the user back to the login page? I don't seem to have access to navigation props there.

Comment: @praveahjain props.navigation

Comment: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.map') I get the above error after clicking onPress

Comment: @BrightLee Hey, if I wanna create a costum style name with icon as a previous element like this =>  " ◘ Logout ", How to handle these

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Getting this error

Comment: How to add multiple content components ??

Answer (score 10):

```
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Mainpage: {
      screen: Mainpage
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent:(props) => (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
              Alert.alert(
                'Log out',
                'Do you want to logout?',
                [
                  {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {return null}},
                  {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {
                    AsyncStorage.clear();
                    props.navigation.navigate('Login')
                  }},
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
              )  
            }>
              <Text style={{margin: 16,fontWeight: 'bold',color: colors.textColor}}>Logout</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    ),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
  }
);
```

Comment: You should import import {DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation'; to get it work.

Comment: Rather than just giving code, it would be more helpful if you explain why it is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Component class for perform Asyncstorage clear and navigate Login Page. If you use react-navigation this.props has navigation object.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

    componentWillMount() {
        Asyncstorage.clear();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage')
    }
}
export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't want to load the component by default. I need to show a confirmation box with "yes" and "No" on click of Logout link. Then after clicking on "Yes" it should load the component.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {StyleSheet,AsyncStorage,Alert, View,SafeAreaView, Text, ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, TextInput,Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {DrawerItems,DrawerActions} from 'react-navigation-drawer';

 {
            contentComponent:(props) => (
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <SideMenu {...props}/>
                    <DrawerItems {...props} />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
                      Alert.alert(
                        'Log out',
                        'Do you want to logout?',
                        [
                          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer()) }},
                          {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {
                            AsyncStorage.clear();
                            props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
                          }},
                        ],
                        { cancelable: false }
                      )
                    }>
                      <Text style={{margin: 16,fontWeight: 'bold',color: 'red'}}>Logout</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ),
            drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
            drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
            drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
    },
```

Comment: Working Fine This code for react navigation version 4. I have tried lot of examples this is best example worked for me @Keshav Gera

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for an answer in navigation version 5 and funcional components:

```
  const getActiveRouteState = function (
    routes: Route<string>[],
    index: number,
    name: string
  ) {
    return routes[index].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  };

function CustomDrawerContent(
    props: DrawerContentComponentProps<DrawerContentOptions>
  ) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          <View>
            <DrawerItem
              icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon type='AntDesign' name='home' />}
              label='Home'
              focused={getActiveRouteState(
                props.state.routes,
                props.state.index,
                'Home'
              )}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate('Home');
              }}
            />
            <DrawerItem
              icon={({ color, size }) => (
                <Icon type='AntDesign' name='minuscircle' />
              )}
              label='Test'
              focused={getActiveRouteState(
                props.state.routes,
                props.state.index,
                'Test'
              )}
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate('Test');
              }}
            />
            <DrawerItem
              icon={({ color, size }) => (
                <Icon type='AntDesign' name='logout' />
              )}
              label='LogOut'
              onPress={async () => {
                await logoutUser();
                setLogginState(false);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

      const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
      const AppDrawerScreen = () => (
        <AppDrawer.Navigator
          drawerPosition='left'
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
        >
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name='Home'
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen name='Test' component={TestScreen} />
        </AppDrawer.Navigator>
      );
```

This will also help you in case you want to hide an option in the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modal which will do this for you. On click of logout -> display modal using visible attribute and on click of yes then close the modal -> navigate to login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just use AlertView bro that will help but in the above example if you have an header than this (this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage'))

will not make any senses

your view will load below the header

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to implement a logout in a drawer using a react-navigation library.

```
<Drawer.Screen
    name="Logout"
    component={<Any Dummy Component>}
    listeners={({ navigation }) => ({ 
        state: (e) => {
           if (e.data.state.index === 3) {
              // 3 is index of logout item in drawer

              navigation.replace("Login")
           }
        }
    })}
/>
```

Comment: Just use what's shown in the auth flow docs instead of doing such hacky things https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: @satya164 With Drawer Navigator, how to perform an action is not provided in the doc. That's why I need to use this solution. Let me know if you find any better solution with a drawer navigator. 

Even in react-navigation git issues, this issue is available but no one has provided a proper solution.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7753

Comment: To sign out, you call "signOut" function which is already defined in the docs

Comment: @satya164 Even for calling signOut, you'll be required listeners. Can you please elaborate more on where I can call "signOut" method. It would be great if you can add any code snippet here.

Comment: I'm not sure why listeners will be needed. Regarding "where", you'd call it on the "onPress" method of the button which is supposed to logout. To add such a button in drawer, there's documentation on how to add custom buttons in drawer: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawercontent

Comment: @satya164 As you have shared, with custom drawer we can use onPress, but when it comes with build-in we don't have onPress listener available with drawerContent. Just for one drawer item use customDrawerContent is not a good option. What do you suggest?

Comment: It's a better option that what you're doing and not even more code.